# Successive minima, polar lattices and local fields

Tags: nt.number-theory

There is a classical result of Mahler relating the successive minima of a lattice $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with the successive minima of its polar
$$
\Lambda^*=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \langle x, y \rangle \in \mathbb{Z} \; \forall y \in \Lambda \};
$$
see for example the Corollary on page 222 in Section VIII.5 of Cassels, "An Introduction to the Geometry of Numbers".

For $\beta$ an algebraic integer, $\mathbb{Z}[\beta]$ is naturally associated to a lattice in some $\mathbb{R}^n$ and this theorem can be applied to a question I'm interested in. However, when $\beta$ is not an algebraic integer, $\mathbb{Z}[\beta]$ will be a lattice not in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but in a finite product $\prod_\nu K_\nu$ for both Archimedean and non-Archimedean completions of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$.

So: Is there a similar result as the above for lattices in product of local fields/the adeles? Any reference would be appreciated.